# How to debug native C++ calling from asp.net using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2017, native

I have an asp.net web application (.NET Framework) by Visual C#, and this web application uses native C++ DLL by DllImport. The native C++ DLL project is also part of the solution. However when I do the debugging, and try to step into the native C++ code, it fails, the breakpoint on the C++ code shows "the breakpoint will not currently be hit no symbols have been loaded".

Comment: You need to load the symbols (`*.pdb` files) for the DLL files.

Comment: “Load the symbols” May not be the solution as visual studio 2017 asp.net does not provide the interface for us to load the symbols for runtime native dll. Instead, vs 2017 does automate the loading process, only thing need to do is make sure the “native code” is checked.

Comment: It does. Open the Modules window and select a native module then choose "Load symbols...".

Comment: It does not, the module windows do show a number of systems native dlls, but it does not show the native c++ dll we created, which the dll project is part of the suloution. During run time, we put a breakpoint on the c# calling c++ place, when breakpoint is hit, the module still does not show the native dll, and I have to pull my hair. (The c# imports our native c++ dll by dllimport.)

Comment: @Shiyu, If possible, not add the solution in the issue directly, you could post your solution as an answer, so you could mark it like this:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work, and then this case can be closed.Thanks for sharing your solution again:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is : make sure The "Native Code" check box (Project>Property>Web>Debugger>native code) as shown on the picture is checked. **By default it is unchecked when the .net project is created**.

I spent whole morning to find out cause, and it is not mentioned in stackoverflow and other website, therefore would like to share the solution.

[image]

//Follow Jack's suggestion to post the solution as an answer, instead of putting it as part of the question. Thanks Jack.